# Lagrange multiplier expression

Tags: optimization, quadratics, quadratic-programming

I would like to solve the following optimization problem using the gradient ascend method:
\begin{array}{ll}
\text{maximize}_{\theta} & \theta^TQ_1\theta + b_1\\
\text{subject to} & \theta^TQ_2\theta+ b_2 \leq \alpha
\end{array}
So I would like to find the langrage multiplier $\lambda$ such that my problem becomes ${\arg\max}_{\theta}~\theta^TQ_1\theta+b_1-\lambda\big(\theta^TQ_2\theta+b_2\big)$ where $\lambda$, $b_1,b_2$ are scalars, $\theta\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times1}$, $Q_1\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ is negative definite and $Q_2\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$ is positive definite. I expect the expression of $\lambda $ to be in terms of $\alpha$ to not violate the constraint $\theta^TQ_2\theta+b_2\leq \alpha$.

Comment: Are there any restrictions placed on $Q_1$ and $Q_2$? (e.g. negative definite)

Comment: @David: yes Q1 is negative definite and Q2 is positive definite and I have edited that in my question.

Comment: Does section 12.3 of this help? http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~cis515/cis515-11-sl12.pdf

Comment: Simplifying the problem might be useful. For example, take out $b_1$ and combine $b_2$ and $\alpha$. Maximize over $\tilde \theta = Q_2^{1/2}\theta$ instead of $\theta$.

Comment: If $\alpha-b_2 < 0$ then the problem is infeasible, so assume $\alpha-b_2 \geq 0$.  In that case the maximum is obviously at $\theta=0$.